# Ideal factorization Theorem, more generally

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Consider Theorem 4.3.1 in [link](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Ant/AntChapter4.pdf)

(it's quite long, so please open the pdf)

I'm wondering if we can assume that the prime ideal we want to decompose is not $(p)$ with $p$ a prime in $\mathbb Q$, but a prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in a number field $K$ which is a subfield of the number field $L$ stated in the theorem.

> Example:
>
> Consider the tower of fields $L:=\mathbb Q(\zeta_8)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 2,i) -- >K:=\mathbb Q(i) -- \mathbb Q$
>
> Now I'd like to decompose the ideal $\mathfrak p = (1+i)\lhd \mathcal O_K$ in $\mathcal O_L$. Replacing $\mathbb Z$ by $\mathcal O_K$ in the theorem, we choose $\theta = \sqrt 2$ with minimal polynomial $x^2-2$. This polynomial reduces to $\bar f= x^2$, since $(2)\subset (1+i)$.
>
> Then, if this version of the Theorem would be correct, the decomposition would be $(1+i)=(1+i,\sqrt 2)^2$. The correct decomposition should be $(1+i)=(1+\zeta_8)^2$, but $1+\zeta_8=1+(1+i)/\sqrt 2$ is not in (1+i,\sqrt 2) (or am I missing something?).
>
> > If we take the extension $\mathbb Q(\zeta_8) -- \mathbb Q$, the Theorem works as stated in the pdf  and everything is fine: $(2)\mathcal O_L=(1+\zeta_8)^4$.

Answer (score 0):

The result of Kummer in Theorem $4.3.1$ is about the decomposition of a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}=(p)$ with a rational prime $p$ in $B=\mathcal{O}_L$, the ring of algebraic integers in $L$. In general, however, we can start with a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ in $\mathcal{O}_K$, and consider its decomposition 
$$
\mathfrak{p}\mathcal{O}_L=P_1^{e_1}\cdots P_r^{e_r}
$$

in $\mathcal{O}_L$, where $L/K$ is an extension of number fields.

Comment: And does the theorem then say 'assume that there is a $\theta$ such that $\mathcal O_L=\mathcal O_K[\theta]$' ... and '$f\in \mathcal O_K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $\theta$'?